# C# example through microsoft graph explorer says undefined method

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Your c# example for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$search="jesper"

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var people = await graphClient.Me.People
.Request()
.Search("jesper")
.GetAsync();
```

Error I'm getting:

[image]

not sure if this is meant to happen but seems wrong that you cant use the search function
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Maybe you use functions from [Microsoft.Graph.Beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/) instead of [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/)?

Comment: just tried with graph beta and i get the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're absolutely right. Those snippets are generated by a tool, and sometimes it gets it wrong. Thanks for reporting!

You can add any query parameters to requests sent by the SDK though, so you can still make this work like so:

```
var options = new List<QueryOption> { new QueryOption("$search", "j") };
var people = await graphClient.Me.People.Request(options).GetAsync();
```

Comment: May i ask after doing the request like this it returns a IUserPeopleCollectionPage which it either seems like it doesnt apply the search (because it returns all people in the organization) or  i just dont understand how to get the searched person out of the list of people it returns.

Comment: It should only return people that satisfy your search. Try the same query in Graph Explorer, are the results different?

Comment: Not sure what actually happens but it only happens on the c# end heres the c# code https://imgur.com/WKRi7jo and the result is here https://imgur.com/yikO7mj and then i use the graph explorer it only returns 3 objects with the same search string https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/people?$search="Jesper Jakobsen"

Comment: Try wrapping your string in double-quotes like `"\"Jesper Jakobsen\""`. The code you have results in a query like `?$search=Jesper%20Jakobsen`, which isn't exactly the same as your Graph Explorer query.